# How to inset plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The shape files of China map data can be downloaded from “https://github.com/liuyanguu/Blogdown/tree/master/Data/China.shp”, and I saved  all the three files: bou2_4p.dbf, bou2_4p.shp, and bou2_4p.shx within the same folder at "D:/map data".

First open the file of "u2_4p.shp" by using:

```
setwd(D:/map data)
library (rgdal)
china_map = readOGR (file.choose()) # select "u2_4p.shp" and open it
```

Then I prepare the data and plot the map as below:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

china_map@data$province <- iconv(china_map@data$NAME, from = "CP936", to = "UTF-8")
china_map@data$id = rownames(china_map@data)
china.points = fortify(china_map, region="id")
china.df = join(china.points, china_map@data, by="id")

data2=data.frame(city=c("NJ","AH","BJ","CD","CQ"),
                 count=c(15,32,45,52,24),
                 lat=c(32,31,39,29,29),
                 long=c(118,117,116,111,106))

ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=china.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill= "white", color="grey40")+
  geom_point(data = data2, aes(x = long, y = lat, size=count, color=count, alpha=count))+
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10)) +
  scale_color_viridis(option="inferno", trans="log" ) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(trans="log")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

As you can see the map plot shown as below:
[image]

I'd like to know how to add the South China Sea Area at the corner of the picture as below:
[image]

Comment: package {cowplot}, among others, offers convenient functions to insert plots: https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html

Comment: Have you tried searching "r inset map"? there seem to be lots of options. Heres a relatively recent one: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/03/insets-with-ggplot2-and-tmap-and-mapsf/

Answer (score 1):

The package {cowplot} can solve the problem. Also the data of South China Sea need to be added.

The data can be downloaded from:
"http://gaohr.win/site/blogs/2017/2017-04-18-GIS-basic-data-of-China.html"
[image]

Along with the china map data downloaded from "https://github.com/liuyanguu/Blogdown/tree/master/Data/China.shp", I saved all the files in "D:/map data".

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(viridis)

l9=rgdal::readOGR("D:/map data/九段线.shp")
china_map=readShapePoly("D:/map data/bou2_4p.shp")

china_map@data$province <- iconv(china_map@data$NAME, from = "CP936", to = "UTF-8")
china_map@data$id = rownames(china_map@data)
china.points = fortify(china_map, region="id")
china.df = join(china.points, china_map@data, by="id")

data2=data.frame(city=c("NJ","AH","BJ","CD","CQ"),
                 count=c(15,32,45,52,24),
                 lat=c(32,31,39,29,29),
                 long=c(118,117,116,111,106))

p1=ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=china.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill= "white", color="grey40")+
  geom_point(data = data2, aes(x = long, y = lat, size=count, color=count, alpha=count))+
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10)) +
  scale_color_viridis(option="inferno", trans="log" ) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(trans="log")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2=ggplot()+
geom_polygon(data=china.df,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color="grey40",fill="white")+
  geom_line(data=l9,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color="red",linewidth=0.5)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(105,125),ylim=c(3,30))+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.25,
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA,color="grey20",linetype=1,linewidth=0.8),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,-1,-1),"mm")
        )

library(cowplot)
ggdraw()+
  draw_plot(p1)+
  draw_plot(p2,height=0.25,x=0.37,y=0.12)
```

[image]